# Apex trigger logic into Apex class

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to put the below apex trigger logic into apex class and call it. Can anyone please help me in writing it - Below is the trigger -

```
trigger AT_oldActivity on Activity_Tracker__c(before update){

    for(Activity_Tracker__c at : Trigger.new){
        Activity_Tracker__c atprior = Trigger.oldMap.get(at.id);
        at.Start_Date_Prior_Value__c = at.Start_Date__c;
        at.End_Date_Prior_Value__c = at.End_Date__c;
        at.Status_Prior_value__c = at.Status__c;
        at.Updates_prior_value__c = at.Updates__c;
        at.Description_prior_value__c = at.Description__c;

        if(at.Start_Date__c <> atprior.Start_Date__c){
            at.Start_Date_Prior_Value__c = atprior.Start_Date__c;
        }
        if(at.End_Date__c <> atprior.End_Date__c ){
            at.End_Date_Prior_Value__c = atprior.End_Date__c;
        }
        if(at.Status__c <> atprior.Status__c){
            at.Status_Prior_value__c = atprior.Status__c;

        }
        if(at.Updates__c <> atprior.Updates__c){
            at.Updates_prior_value__c = atprior.Updates__c;
        }
        if(at.Description__c <> atprior.Description__c){
            at.Description_prior_value__c = atprior.Description__c;
        }
        if(at.Revised_End_Date__c <> atprior.Revised_End_Date__c){
            at.Revised_End_Prior_Date__c = atprior.Revised_End_Date__c;
        }
        // Edit Access to Action Ownere and CoE Lead fields  
        if(at.Action_Owner__c != at.OwnerId  && at.Action_Owner__c == UserInfo.getUserId() ){
            if(atprior.Name!= at.Name||atprior.RAG_Status__c!= at.RAG_Status__c||atprior.Category__c != at.Category__c|| atprior.End_Date__c!= at.End_Date__c ||atprior.RAG_Status__c!= at.RAG_Status__c ||atprior.Revised_End_Date__c!= at.Revised_End_Date__c ||atprior.Instance__c!= at.Instance__c ||atprior.Start_Date__c!= at.Start_Date__c ||atprior.Start_Date__c!= at.Start_Date__c){
                at.addError (System.Label.Activity_Update_Desc);            
            }        
         }
       if(UserInfo.getName()<>'AXABS Admin1' && UserInfo.getName()<>'AXABS Admin2' && at.OwnerId != UserInfo.getUserId()){
       system.debug('@@@@@' + UserInfo.getName());
         if(atprior.Start_Date__c != at.Start_Date__c  || atprior.End_Date__c != at.End_Date__c ){
          at.addError (System.Label.Activity_Start_End_Date);
        }
      }       
  }          
 }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below code.

Trigger:

```
trigger AT_oldActivity on Activity_Tracker__c(before update){

    AT_oldActivityHandler.AT_oldActivity(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldmap);         
 }
```

Handler class :

```
public class AT_oldActivityHandler{

    public static void AT_oldActivity(List<Activity_Tracker__c> lstActivityTrackerNew,map<id,Activity_Tracker__c> mapActivityTrackerOld){

        for(Activity_Tracker__c at : lstActivityTrackerNew){
        Activity_Tracker__c atprior = mapActivityTrackerOld.get(at.id);
        at.Start_Date_Prior_Value__c = at.Start_Date__c;
        at.End_Date_Prior_Value__c = at.End_Date__c;
        at.Status_Prior_value__c = at.Status__c;
        at.Updates_prior_value__c = at.Updates__c;
        at.Description_prior_value__c = at.Description__c;

        if(at.Start_Date__c <> atprior.Start_Date__c){
            at.Start_Date_Prior_Value__c = atprior.Start_Date__c;
        }
        if(at.End_Date__c <> atprior.End_Date__c ){
            at.End_Date_Prior_Value__c = atprior.End_Date__c;
        }
        if(at.Status__c <> atprior.Status__c){
            at.Status_Prior_value__c = atprior.Status__c;

        }
        if(at.Updates__c <> atprior.Updates__c){
            at.Updates_prior_value__c = atprior.Updates__c;
        }
        if(at.Description__c <> atprior.Description__c){
            at.Description_prior_value__c = atprior.Description__c;
        }
        if(at.Revised_End_Date__c <> atprior.Revised_End_Date__c){
            at.Revised_End_Prior_Date__c = atprior.Revised_End_Date__c;
        }
        // Edit Access to Action Ownere and CoE Lead fields  
        if(at.Action_Owner__c != at.OwnerId  && at.Action_Owner__c == UserInfo.getUserId() ){
            if(atprior.Name!= at.Name||atprior.RAG_Status__c!= at.RAG_Status__c||atprior.Category__c != at.Category__c|| atprior.End_Date__c!= at.End_Date__c ||atprior.RAG_Status__c!= at.RAG_Status__c ||atprior.Revised_End_Date__c!= at.Revised_End_Date__c ||atprior.Instance__c!= at.Instance__c ||atprior.Start_Date__c!= at.Start_Date__c ||atprior.Start_Date__c!= at.Start_Date__c){
                at.addError (System.Label.Activity_Update_Desc);            
            }        
         }
       if(UserInfo.getName()<>'AXABS Admin1' && UserInfo.getName()<>'AXABS Admin2' && at.OwnerId != UserInfo.getUserId()){
       system.debug('@@@@@' + UserInfo.getName());
         if(atprior.Start_Date__c != at.Start_Date__c  || atprior.End_Date__c != at.End_Date__c ){
          at.addError (System.Label.Activity_Start_End_Date);
        }
      }       
  } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger will be as below,

```
trigger AT_oldActivity on Activity_Tracker__c(before update){
     List<Activity_Tracker__c> lstActivity = new List<Activity_Tracker__c>();
     for(Activity_Tracker__c at : Trigger.New){
         lstActivity.add(at);
     }
     TriggerUtility.updateActivity(lstActivity);
}
```

Your class will be as below,

```
public class TriggerUtility{

public static void updateActivity(List<Activity_Tracker__c> lstActivity ){
   for(Activity_Tracker__c at : lstActivity ){
    Activity_Tracker__c atprior = (Activity_Tracker__c) Trigger.oldMap.get(at.id);
    at.Start_Date_Prior_Value__c = at.Start_Date__c;
    at.End_Date_Prior_Value__c = at.End_Date__c;
    at.Status_Prior_value__c = at.Status__c;
    at.Updates_prior_value__c = at.Updates__c;
    at.Description_prior_value__c = at.Description__c;

    if(at.Start_Date__c <> atprior.Start_Date__c){
        at.Start_Date_Prior_Value__c = atprior.Start_Date__c;
    }
    if(at.End_Date__c <> atprior.End_Date__c ){
        at.End_Date_Prior_Value__c = atprior.End_Date__c;
    }
    if(at.Status__c <> atprior.Status__c){
        at.Status_Prior_value__c = atprior.Status__c;

    }
    if(at.Updates__c <> atprior.Updates__c){
        at.Updates_prior_value__c = atprior.Updates__c;
    }
    if(at.Description__c <> atprior.Description__c){
        at.Description_prior_value__c = atprior.Description__c;
    }
    if(at.Revised_End_Date__c <> atprior.Revised_End_Date__c){
        at.Revised_End_Prior_Date__c = atprior.Revised_End_Date__c;
    }
    // Edit Access to Action Ownere and CoE Lead fields  
    if(at.Action_Owner__c != at.OwnerId  && at.Action_Owner__c == UserInfo.getUserId() ){
        if(atprior.Name!= at.Name||atprior.RAG_Status__c!= at.RAG_Status__c||atprior.Category__c != at.Category__c|| atprior.End_Date__c!= at.End_Date__c ||atprior.RAG_Status__c!= at.RAG_Status__c ||atprior.Revised_End_Date__c!= at.Revised_End_Date__c ||atprior.Instance__c!= at.Instance__c ||atprior.Start_Date__c!= at.Start_Date__c ||atprior.Start_Date__c!= at.Start_Date__c){
            at.addError (System.Label.Activity_Update_Desc);            
        }        
     }
   if(UserInfo.getName()<>'AXABS Admin1' && UserInfo.getName()<>'AXABS Admin2' && at.OwnerId != UserInfo.getUserId()){
     system.debug('@@@@@' + UserInfo.getName());
     if(atprior.Start_Date__c != at.Start_Date__c  || atprior.End_Date__c != at.End_Date__c ){
      at.addError (System.Label.Activity_Start_End_Date);
        }
      }       
  }          
}
```

Comment: Hi Sneha. Thanks for the help . I am getting " Compile Error: Illegal assignment from SObject to Activity_Tracker__c at line 5 column 5" error while saving. Can u please check.Thanks very much..